# Bottom menu not working in my WordPress project using the given CSS

Tags: css, wordpress, media-queries

I was wondering if anybody can help me with a problem I am stuck on at the moment.
I am working on a wordpress project via Udemy, and following instructions, but my results are not working correctly.

The bottom menu should not show when in mobile view but as you can see in my screenshot, its still showing:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8AUM.png)

here is my CSS code for the footer menu:

/**footer**/

```
.site-footer{
    border-top: 2px solid var(--lightGray);
    padding:2rem 0;

}
.footer-content{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.footer-menu{
    display: none;
}
@media (min-width: 768px){
    .footer-menu .menu{
        display: flex;
    }

    .footer-menu .menu li{
        margin-right: 2rem;
    }
    .footer-menu .menu li:last-of-type{
        margin-right: 0;
    }


     .footer-menu a{
        font-family: var(--mainFont);
        font-size: 1.8rem;
        color: var(--black);
    }
}
```

**update **
It seems that as yet I have had mo luck with this-
I would like someone to test the code with me to find what the problem is.
I have put it on github if anyone would like to help.
Many thanks

Comment: Would you like to show the Footer menu only in mobile devices, not in desktop?

Comment: I want to hide the footer menu in mobile, but show it in desktop. - I thought the the .footer-menu{display:none}  would hide the botton nav in Mobile.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide the Footer menu in mobile then you have to `display: none` that menu div in media query of 768px.

```
@media(max-width:768px){
    .footer-menu{display: none;}
}
```

So first, the menu will show in desktop you not need to add `display: none` first.
You can add that in the @media query.

Remove the below CSS from desktop:

```
.footer-menu{
    display: none;
}
```

and add this one in media query which I have mentioned above.

```
@media(max-width:768px){
     .footer-menu .menu{
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211763/discussion-on-answer-by-krupal-panchal-bottom-menu-not-working-in-my-wordpress-p).

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing our html I cannot say for sure what is the problem. My advice would be

1. Check that your html has the correct classes applied.
2. If its not that make sure you are loading the lastest css file* and that it is not loading an older version from the cache**.

*While doing your development you can force wordpress to load the latest css file by adding the modified time as a version parameter in your functions.php file when enqueing the css:

```
$modified = filemtime( get_template_directory() . '/style.css');
wp_enqueue_style( 'SLUG-style', get_stylesheet_uri(), array(), $modified );
```

**In chrome you can use dev tools to clear the cache (ctrl + shift + i), right click on refresh then click 'empty cache and hard reload'.

Comment: Here is my footer code:

<footer class="site-footer container">
<div class="footer-content">

<?php
$args = array(
    'theme_location'=> 'main-menu',
    'container' => 'nav',
    'container_class' => 'footer-menu'
);
wp_nav_menu( $args );
?>
<p class="copyright">All rights reserved . <?php echo get_bloginfo('name') . " " . date('Y'); ?> </p>
</div>


</footer>

<?php wp_footer(); ?>



</body>
</html>

Comment: No. as soon as i got to mobile mode the menu appears, not sure why, why i have it sa {display:none}